# jQuery .html Facebook Embed

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I´m trying to use jQuery to change the content of a div.
I came across the .html function.

This is the Embed Code from Facebook:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1281569608559738";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And this is the Code that needs to go into the div I want to display it at :

```
<div class="fb-post" data-href="////LINK///" data-show-text="true">
                            <blockquote cite="////LINK///" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                        </div>
```

So I used this website : http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/

To change the code to this :

```
var strVar="";
strVar += "<div class=\"fb-post\" data-href=\""+ link + "" data-show-text=\"true\">";
strVar += "                             <blockquote cite=\""+ link + "" class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\">";
strVar += "                         <\/div>";
```

link is a variable.
And later I use .html like this :

```
$( "#iFramePlace" ).html(strVar);
```

But nothing happens. And I can´t figure out why.

The whole code:

```
    <html>
<head>

    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {

                    function ApiRequest(l) {
                        $.get("apiServer/?l=" + l, function(data) {
                                var ServerResult = JSON.parse(data);
                                if (ServerResult.error == false) {
                                    if (ServerResult.platform == 'fb') {
                                        if (ServerResult.typ == 'fanpage') {
                                            var output = "";
                                            output += "<div class=\"fb-post\" data-href=\"" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\" data-show- text=\"true\">";
                                            output += "                             <blockquote cite=\"" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\" class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\">";
                                            output += "                         <\/div>";
                                            $("#iFramePlace").html(output);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        alert("Mit dem Link stimmt etwas nicht !")
                                    }
                                });
                        }
                        $("#btnForm").click(function() {
                            var link = $("#link").val();
                            if (link !== "")
                                ApiRequest(link);
                            else
                                alert("LINK FEHLT");
                        });

                        console.log("ready!");
                    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="link" name="inputText" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnForm" name="SubmitButton" />
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1281569608559738";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div id="iFramePlace"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Regards !

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes look off in this block:

```
var strVar="";
strVar += "<div class=\"fb-post\" data-href=\""+ link + "" data-show- text=\"true\">";
strVar += "                             <blockquote cite=\""+ link + "" class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\">";
strVar += "                         <\/div>";
```

Try:

```
var strVar="";
strVar += "<div class=\"fb-post\" data-href=\""+ link + "\" data-show- text=\"true\">";
strVar += "                             <blockquote cite=\""+ link + "\" class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\">";
strVar += "                         <\/div>";
```

edit:

You've got several problems with this javascript:

I'd suggest keeping all your javascript in the same set of  tags - I'm also not sure what the js that's written in your body is even intended to do.

$(function(){}); is a short hand for $(document).ready(function() {}); which indicates code to fire when the page is loaded - function definitions should be outside of this block.

If this function succeeds, the div you are inserting does not actually show any visible content and has no height.  You can see the div if you inspect element, but in the fiddle I added some css to make it show up.

I did not test your JSON to see if it was returning data, as I think that is a seperate issue.

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3s345tLp/1/)

Comment: No still nothing. I don´t get it. 

The div just gets some height but nothing in it .

Comment: Could you post the entirety of your html and javascript?  Have you tried debugging in your browser with js breakpoints?

Comment: I added it to the inital post

Comment: No one has a solution to this ?